# PostgreSQL : Update column with same vaue

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Following is sample table and data

```
create table chk_vals (vals text);

insert into chk_vals values ('1|2|4|3|9|8|34|35|38|1|37|1508|1534');
```

So,How to update column `vals` by appending integer in 4th position of the existing value(*ie. `3` `|` is used as a seperator*) into the last position along with symbol `|`

as you can see the existsing value if `1|2|4|3|9|8|34|35|38|1|37|1508|1534`  and the  output should be `1|2|4|3|9|8|34|35|38|1|37|1508|1534|3`

Answer (score 2):

Use   PostgreSQL's [**split_part()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html) to splits the field and find the value at position `4`

```
select split_part(vals,'|',4) val from chk_vals
```

this will return value `3`

```
 update chk_vals 
 set vals=vals||format('|%s',(select split_part(vals,'|',4) val from chk_vals))
```

[**Format()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)